# Cannot drop database because it is currently in use - EF code-first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, connection-string

In my configuration I have this:

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<App.Repository.NogginatorDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(AppDbContext context)
    {
        SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
        //context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AppDbContext>());

        if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("TestConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
        }
     }
 }
```

This is used for a test db that *should* drop and recreate every time.  Though when I hit "update-database" from the package manager console, even if the database is deleted manually prior to running, I get:

> Cannot drop database "Nogginator.Test" because it is currently in use.

My connection string:

```
<add name="TestConnection" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=App.Test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
```

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Do you have the database open in SSMS or something similar?

Comment: @Pete No, SSMS is open but I deleted / closed all connection on the target db.  If I close SSMS and try again, I get the same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you were recently debugging your web application, ensure that the IIS Express isn't still running and that there are no w3wp.exe processes associated with IIS Express. This process may still be holding on to a database connection.

Comment: +Also make sure the connection is closed in the Server Explorer (if you opened a connection there)

Comment: @rob Good call on that one, too! That bit me also just the other day.